# devforce 2012 store navigation example cocktail

Tags: devforce

I looked at the NavSample from the cocktail 2012 package and wondered where the 'SelectedCustomer' is bound. 
Somehow the listview does this. 
I suppose it's a Caliburn thing, but i cannot see the logic.

Comment: Please add a SSCCE to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's bind to the SelectedCustomer defined in the ViewModel thanks to one of the caliburn's convention.

The component is named Customers like the Collection in the ViewModel. Caliburn will try to find a property named Customers and will bind the component to it. 
The convention for the listbox say if it find a property named like "Selected" + name of the component it will bind the Selected property to it

You can find more informations about the caliburn conventions there : https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Conventions